# mootools $ (dollar) function and document.createElement equivalence

Tags: javascript, mootools

In the following code is the second line redundant? doesn't the first line return a reference to the created div? or am I missing something is there any change required to port this to jquery?

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
var div = $(div);
div.id='tip_holder';
div.style.zIndex=10000;
div.style.left='-1000em';
body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` adds the mootools stuff to the element. To make it redundant you need to re-write this (and I also rewrote some extra redundant code there)

```
var div = new Element('DIV',{'id': 'tip_holder',
                             'styles':{
                                         zIndex:10000,
                                         left:'-1000em'                    

}});
$$('body')[0].adopt(div);
```

If you allready have a valid reference to the body from somewhere, just use

```
$(body).adopt(div); //no " needed
```

or

```
body.adopt(div);//if it is already a mootools Element
```

Comment: do I need to change anything in original code to port it to jquery or it works pretty much the same way?

Comment: I do not know how you create an element in JQuery, guess it is pretty much the same. What bothers you that makes you want to migrate?

Comment: there is a lot of jquery code so trying to port everything over to it instead of using two libraries

Comment: I just use both, and they play nicely, replacte the `$` of mootools with `document.id()` and se tu

Comment: `new Element("div#tip_holder").setStyles({zIndex:10000,left:'-1000em'}).inject(document.body);` - `inject` vs `append`? or use the mootools `adopt` check the `mootools` api.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - thanks, got mixing the API, (adopt vs append)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element), the `$` function is just a map for the `document.id` function. And the `document.id` function does only two things:

- If you give it a string, it returns the element that has that id.
- If you give it an element (as you're doing in your example) and the current browser doesn't have native `HTMLElement` support (ahem, IE), then the element is expanded with some new methods.